# Getting slightly different output every time after running the same code

Tags: python

Here in this code I am getting output differently every time I run the same code.

INPUT:

```
s='AABCAAADA'
st=[]
def merge_the_tools(size,k):
    n=int(len(size)/k)
    for i in range(n):
        st.append(size[i*n:(i+1)*n])
    for i in st:
        se=set(i)
        print(''.join(se))
        
print(merge_the_tools(s,3))
```

First OUTPUT:

```
AB
AC
AD
None
```

Another OUTPUT:

```
AB
CA
DA
None
```

Another OUTPUT:

```
BA
CA
DA
None
```

Like this I am getting different output
Can anybody tell why this is happening.

And I want this OUTPUT:

```
AB
CA
AD
```

Comment: Sets in Python don't have a specific order.

Comment: So, what can we do here to get any specific order

Comment: Sort the content of the set to obtain always the same order.

Answer (score 1):

Python `set`s have no order, so there is no guarantee that the items will be retrieved in the same order every time while `join`ing them. Consider using a `list` or `tuple` if you would like to maintain order.

Answer (score 1):

Sets in Python are unordered and unindexed [as shown in this demonstration](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp). If you want to maintain a specific order, you can just sort the set as follows.

```py
print(''.join(sorted(se)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `set` in Python is an unordered data structure, so so it does not preserve the insertion order.

You should use a `list` instead. Or you can `sort` the set. But `sort` return a list anyway.

Using `sorted`:

```py
s='AABCAAADA'
st=[]
def merge_the_tools(size,k):
    n=int(len(size)/k)
    for i in range(n):
        st.append(size[i*n:(i+1)*n])
    for i in st:
        se=set(i)
        print(''.join(sorted(se)))
        
print(merge_the_tools(s,3))
```